# Custom FXML Annotations

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

For some additional/custom attributes, like tab indices or tool tip texts, it would be nice to annotate the FXML with custom annotations. I have three proposals for it:

XML-Comment:

```
<!-- @TabIndex(index=1) -->
<Button fx:id="test_audio" text="Test" />
```

fx attribute:

```
<Button fx:id="test_audio" fx:tab_index="1" text="Test" />
```

Custom XML namespace attribute :

```
<Button fx:id="test_audio" custom:tab_index="1" text="Test" />
```

Is there a way to do this and get the attribute values on runtime?

Comment: I recommend to start this discussion on the openjfx-dev mailing list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev

Comment: Puce, I agree with you, but I hoped that any kind of custom annotation is allready implemented. The proposals are meant to give a an idea, what I mean.